# Is it dangerous to use a window's datacontext after its closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, garbage-collection

Lets say I got a window which defined a datacontext inside xaml

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

in the code I opened up this window and I wish to use read its datacontext to retrieve the data like

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
w.ShowDialog();
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel) w.DataContext;
```

is this dangerous? I am assuming my window might be subject to GC after ShowDialog ends which would cause the `w.DataContext` line to fail in some unlucky situation. Is it suggested that I sets the datacontext inside code to keep the reference around to prevent GC? (I like to specify the VM inside xaml when the VM does not need special initialization and the View only uses that one instance of VM. Also it makes it easy to find out which VM the view uses and it enables auto complete feature)

Comment: generally speaking, using some resource after you relinquish control of it is dangerous. There is NO guarantee that anything involved with that resource hasn't been repurposed for something else. it's like storing your engagement ring in a garbage can, then being surprised that the can was emptied and the space your ring was in is now occupied by a loaded diaper.

Comment: `w` is not subject to garbage collection till after the `w.DataContext` because you are still holding a reference to `w`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good point, so its safe to do then?

Comment: @EdPlunkett because showing the same dialog instance would throw exception? (InvalidOperationException Cannot set Visibility or call Show, ShowDialog, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle after a Window has closed)

Comment: @Steve My mistake: You're absolutely right.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain after thinking about it I think you have a very valid point here. If you want to type out an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

just get it before the `ShowDialog()`

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
ViewModel vm = (ViewModel) w.DataContext;
w.ShowDialog();
```

but actually the only reason I can think of why it wouldn't work otherwise would be that you have an `OnClosed` handler that sets the `DataContext` to `null`.

Also, I'm assuming your ViewModel is a `class` and not a `struct`.

Comment: I was trying to find out whether it is dangerous to get the datacontext after close. But based on Scott's comment it seems like it is not

Answer (score -1):

You can do so, it will be working, because w is still "alive", although the window is closed.

But I suggest to do it another way. You can use design-time intelisence with using DesignInstance:

```
mc:Ignorable="d" 
d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1024"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type={x:Type local:ViewModel}}"
```

You should set the runtime DataContext in Code like

```
MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
w.DataContext = vm;
w.ShowDialog();
// you can work with vm.
```

You can only this way ensure, that the DataContext is a ViewModel. If somebody changes the xaml, and the DataContext is not a ViewModel any more, than your code will not work.